# Отслеживание нажатых кнопок в фоне

Tags: macos, objective-c

Каким образом можно в OS X отследить нажатые кнопки клавиатуры приложением, работающим в фоне (так, как это делает Punto Switcher)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать NSEvent API:

- `+addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` и/или
- `+addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`

---

Пример использования данного API для отслеживания нажатий клавиш: [Writing a Keylogger for OS X](http://blog.pandafox.net/writing-a-keylogger-for-os-x/).

Comment: А можно ли как-то отслеживать еще и нажатия клавиш-модификаторов (ctrl, alt, cmd, …)?

Comment: Конечно. Конкретно для модификаторов есть маска `NSFlagsChangedMasks`.

Comment: @VioLet, спасибо.